# Interface Builder generating non-ARC code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

When I right-click-drag from an object in my storyboard to create a new action, Interface Builder adds it as though I am not using ARC i.e.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
…
- (void)dealloc {
    [_myView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

How can I tell Interface Builder to generate ARC code for me?

Comment: Within your build settings of the project, check the point Objective-C  Automatic Reference Counting. Is that on 'YES'?

Comment: Thanks, the storyboard in question was in a cocoapod. Cocoapods generates all targets with CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=NO.

Comment: Great, I've added it as answer with an appropriate image…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your projects **build settings** and check if ARC is enabled – set to `YES`:

[image]

And, as you mentioned in your comment, for **cocoapods** check the `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=NO` attribute